# migrate a remote CVS repo to SVN using cvs2svn tool

Tags: svn, cvs, cvs2svn

I am trying to migrate a remote CVS repository to SVN using cvs2svn . Below are the steps i am following

```
python cvs2svn --dump-only --dumpfile DUMPFILE.dump pathToRemoteCVSrepo
```

i am getting the following error.

```
ERROR: The specified CVS repository path 'pathToRemoteCVSrepo' is not an existing directory.
```

can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of two things:

1. The cvs2svn tool expects to see a `CVSROOT` directory, just to make sure that this really is a proper server-side repository. It doesn't care what's in the directory, it just needs to be there. You probably copied the directory off the server for conversion and you just need to create a dummy `CVSROOT` directory.

You should end up with something like

```
/path/root/repository_name/
/path/root/repository_name/filename.py,v
/path/root/CVSROOT/
```

2. Is the <pathToRemoteCVSrepo> correct? Did you make a typo? Is it a proper server-side repository with proper ,v files, not just a client-side checkout?

(I'm assuming you're using this tool http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2svn.html )